# How do you use a font-family's special features inside html?

Tags: html, web-development, html5, fonts, css3

How do you use a font-family's symbols, glyphs, ornaments and other features inside?  For example how do you use a font's superscript?

Answer (score 1):

You are after two different things

You insert special characters e.g copyright, accented letters, by using HTML entities e.g. `&copy;` or `&#169;` for ©.  Here is a list https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html

To achieve superscript, it has nothing to do with entities. 
 In this case it is the size and placement of text.

Your HTML would look like this

```
<p>H<span class="atoms">2</span>SO<span class="atoms">4</span> is the chemical formula for sulphuric acid.
But how is this gold Au<span class="charge">2+</span>?</p>
```

the CSS would be

```
p { line-height: 1.5 }

.charge {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0.5em;
    color: red;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.atoms {
    position: relative;
    top: 0.3em;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

This example comes from http://htmldog.com/techniques/superscript/ see it in action here http://htmldog.com/examples/superscript/

I have no association with either of the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Heyy,

Another way to use superscript like this...

HTML CODE

```
  <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>  
</head> 

<body> 
    <p>Examples of superscript</p> 
    <p>2 <sup>4</sup>=16</p> 
    <p>X <sub>4</sub>+ Y<sub>6</sub></p> 
    <p>26<sup>th</sup> of March</p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

CSS CODE

```
sup {
        vertical-align: super;
        font-size: medium;
        color: red;
    }
sub{
      vertical-align: sub;
        font-size: medium;
        color: blue;
    }
```

And you can refer this site for more details https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-subscript-superscript-tags/

For symbols you can refer this link https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_symbols.asp

Comment: Note that that `<sup>` and `<sub>` work fine without the additional CSS.